# How to identify the week within a month with criteria in Excel

Tags: excel

How can I calculate the week of the month? I understand that with the `WEEKNUM` function and `ISOWEEKNUM` function I can get the week of the year but this is not what I am looking for.

A week has only 4 weeks so the function must look at a date written in a cell and only identify a week 1-4

There is one set of criteria that I found especially difficult to add:

**Week 1 for July 2019 begins on `June 30th` - Ends on `July 27th`**

**Week 1 for August begins on `July 28th` - Ends on `August 24th`**

How can something like this added to an excel function?

Comment: What about August 25-31, why does August not have 5 weeks? This sounds like a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

This formula calculates a week in month (assuming your have a date at A1 cell)

```
=WEEKNUM(A1,2)–WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1),2)+1
```

1. Use WEEKNUM to get the week of year.
2. Use WEEKNUM to from the date of the first day of the month the date falls within.
3. Subtract the two week numbers (add 1 in case result is 0 - first week in month).

   Sample:
   8/21/2019

   =WEEKNUM(A1,2) -> 34
   WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1),2) -> 31

   34-31 = 3 -> third week of August

Comment: The formula is calculating up to 5 weeks, for example, 7/28/19 is showing Week 5 when it should be Week 1 of August.

Comment: Can you please take a look when you have a chance